# Apple Developer Swift Tutorial issues - Pressing a button causes iOS app to crash due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to learn how to develop with Xcode and I'm following this Apple Developer tutorial here to get the ball rolling, but I'm running into an issue where in this step, I'm trying to press the button in my simulator.

Tutorial is found here with this step: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1

I'm trying to figure out what's causing the Exception, and I'm finding answers in Objective-C, telling me to turn off Debug messages (it's not this trust me), and trusting private frameworks?

My code is here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func defaultMealName(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

}
```

Help is much appreciated because it's frustrating that I'm following this tutorial to a tooth and I can't even execute a simple app with just a text box, label, and a button!

Comment: Have you deleted outlet to button and added again ?

Comment: Can you provide the text of the exception? Have you changed the name of the touch up inside handler function  and not relinked it from interface builder?

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Wow that worked! Thank you so much! I tried deleting the function but I didn't try to just delete the button. How come it works like that??

Comment: When you delete outlet you must delete it from the button, as newbie everyone face this crash, after  all, we learn from our mistakes, Keep Going

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I don't remember ever deleting the outlet..so if I ever delete an outlet, I need to delete the button again? Is there another way to reassociate it?

Comment: No, you don't need to delete button, Instead, right-click on that button and see if your deleted outlet/ Action  is still associated with the button

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Wow I'll keep that in mind, thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @m1771vw - Always welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is wrong connection between your button in the Storyboard and the action method. 
You can:

1. Delete the button, insert another button and reconnect the action on it
2. Right click on the button in the storyboard. This show you all the connection. Check if there is a wrong or multiple connection and delete it. You must have only one connection with the correct class. See the picture.[image]

Comment: Woops, I had it answered in my comments, but thanks for showing all of it!